# Angular material add semi colon after every 2 characters

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code which is an Angular Material input field that a user can type in a MAC Address. I want to have the ability to add a colon(:) after every 2 characters a user types in. And also if a user deletes a character next to a colon it should remove that specific colon

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['mac_address']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Any ideas how to do this in Angular 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an event in your input, and then do what you need in a separate variable using `model.mac_address`.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="changedInput($event)" placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['mac_address']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then add the function

```
public changedInput(value){
 if(this.model.mac_address){
   //we do not need the value, we just update the formatedMac using this.model.mac_address
   const inputWithourColon = this.model.mac_address.replace(new RegExp(";", 'g'), "");
   let blocks = inputWithourColon.match(/.{1,2}/g);
   let formatedMac = blocks.shift();
   for (let block of blocks){
    formatedMac = formatedMac + ";" + block;
   }
   this.model.mac_address = formatedMac;
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed (change) directive with (keyup) and updated code to write the formated text **inside** the input field while the user writes.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this

Comment: ok it is actually working, it just needs to show the result in the input field which the user is typing in

Comment: Ok @eohdev , I made several changes, take a look, it should do what you need now.

Comment: one more thing @hjbello. When I delete a character after the colon eg '11:11:', is it possible to remove the '':"

Comment: Yes @eohdev I edited the code again. It suffices to change (keypress) with (keyup) in the html

Comment: I've also added a .trim() to the `(new RegExp(";", 'g'), "")` to remove white-space